# $x$-axis is meager set on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Subset $A$ of metric space $X$ is **meager** on $X$, iff $\text{IntCl}A=\emptyset$.

But, why $x$-axis is meager set on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

My attempt (please don't kill me):

$\text{IntCl}\mathbb{R}=\text{Int}\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\neq \emptyset$

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The interior of $\mathbb{R}$ as a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is very different from its interior as a standalone topological space.

Given any point $P$ on the $x$-axis, every open neighbourhood of $P$ contains a point not on the $x$-axis. So $P$ is not in the interior of the $x$-axis. To put it another way, every point of the $x$-axis is on the *boundary* of the $x$-axis.

Comment: But does this show the closure of R as a subset of $R^2$ is empty? In other words, I am asking what IS the closure of $R$ as a subset

Comment: The $x$-axis is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the "$x$-axis" as a *subspace of $\Bbb R^2$* should be

$$A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \Bbb R^2:x_2=0\}$$

To aid André's answer:

> In mathematics, a *nowhere dense set* in a topological space is a set whose closure has empty interior [viz ${\rm int}({\rm cl}(A))=\varnothing$].
>
> **The order of operations is important**. For example, the set of rational numbers, as a subset of $\Bbb R$ has the property that the interior has an empty closure, but it is not nowhere dense; in fact it is dense in $\Bbb R$.
>
> **The surrounding space matters**: a set $A$ may be nowhere dense when considered as a subspace of a topological space $X$ but not when considered as a subspace of another topological space $Y$. A nowhere dense set is always dense in itself.

Something more, plus *terminology*:

> Every subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense, and the union of finitely many nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense. That is, the nowhere dense sets form an ideal of sets, a suitable notion of negligible set. **The union of countably many nowhere dense sets, however, need not be nowhere dense. (...) Instead, such a union is called a meagre set or a set of first category.**

Answer (score 1):

I think to find interior of $X$ axis in $R_2$, take any $x$ on $X$, every neighborhood of $x$ should completely lie on $X$ axis which is not possible as we are in $R_2$ (Since neighborhood in $R_2$ is an open ball), thus interior of $X$ axis is empty and hence that of $\text {Cl(X - axis)}$ (because $X$ axis is closed in $R_2$ with euclidean metric)

Is this true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, check the following [guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how to provide effective answers. In particular, please, check your English and your formatting and don't post answers if you first are not sure they are correct. Either opt for a comment or ask a new question.